# Wordpress site won't draw some visualizations, gives "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.I()')" error

Tags: wordpress, google-visualization, draw, visualizer

I recently completed this website project: http://cunninghamk1.journalismanddesign.com/?page_id=150 It all seemed to work well for about a month, until I went back to it a few days ago. I haven't made any changes to anything on the site, except a bit of CSS related to the header.

On the examples and tutorials page, I have two data visualizations that no longer will draw. One (no. 3 on that page) is made with a Wordpress plugin, which I have updated. The other (no. 6 on that page) works with the Google Charts API. I don't see a commonality with the problems, and I'm not sure how to fix either one. I've redone the charts with Visualizer (the plugin) but I get the same error, which says 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.I()').
I've gone back to the .js file for this but nothing has changed or seems amiss otherwise.

Thanks for any ideas on what might be causing the problem.

Comment: I isolated the visualizer code, and ran those charts, and it worked fine.  I couldn't locate the source of your other charts in a quick search of the code.

Comment: Thank you, asgallant. Any idea why it's not working on my end?  Trying to think of what could prevent it from showing up.

Comment: Also, what's the best way to show you the source of the other charts? Even with the code markdown, I keep exceeding the character limit here. Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a small test page that shows the problem, then post the source for that.

Comment: So I created this page as a test and the pie charts do draw: http://cunninghamk1.journalismanddesign.com/?p=742 Is it possible there is something else on the page that is preventing the pie charts from drawing or the plugin from working? For the separate problem with the Google Charts API viz (number six here: http://cunninghamk1.journalismanddesign.com/?page_id=150, I pasted the .js file below the pie charts on the same page listed at the start of this entry. Inside wordpress, I just have a link to that .js file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any problems there.  The only potential issue I see is trying to load the API multiple times (as there is call to `google.load` in the main page, in the visualizer script, and in your custom code).  As I recall, the first load call wins in that case, which means some API components that each script needs may not be getting loaded.